# Charging 18650 Lipos with PCB and micro USB breakout board

Tags: batteries, usb, lipo

I have a circuit with 2 18650 Lipos, which are connected to a 2s PCB Protection Board which has a p+ and p- connector for out- and input. My question is whether I can charge the two batteries by connecting the v+ and grnd pins of a simple micro USB breakout board to the p+ and p- pins? Are the 5V of the USB board enough to charge the two 7.4 V batteries? 
Here's the PCB board on eBay:
https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.de%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F253581817900

Comment: It should be clear that you cannot charge a 7.4V 2S battery with 5V without a boost charger circuit. The protection board you have is for ensuring balancing during charging. It is NOT a charge controller.

Comment: @JackCreasy   Will something like this do the trick? https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.de%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F323267736533

Comment: Or is a simple voltage step up converter enough?

Comment: You need a charger that is able to understand the voltage and current profile of  charging. So yes, the charger would do the trick.